# why can't django return a plain text response with a link to download the file?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, response, django-orm

I have in Django eksport functionality, in the custom admin.
So, when requesting to get everything from the database, I make an ORM query of the necessary sample - the query is heavy, but it works fine, I get the data at once, no more trips to the database.
Then comes the functionality of working with this data, shoved everywhere there, processed, and finally shoved into the dataframe pandas and written to a CSV file, and saved in the directory (before that immediately tried to give the user), the file weighs about 280mb.
So, what is the actual problem, the real file is saved quickly relatively, but the response to the user can come from half an hour, just with a link to download the file.

```
def save_data_in_csv_file(df_jewelry):
    """write data

    Attributes:
    - df_jewelry: data frame pandas +- 1_300_000 rows.
    """

    download_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'download_file')

    if not os.path.exists(download_folder):
        os.makedirs(download_folder)

    file_path = os.path.join(download_folder, 'output.csv')

    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
        df_jewelry.to_csv(file, index=False)

    download_link = (
        'path_to_file'
    )

    response_data = {
        'message': 'File save!',
        'download_link': download_link,
    }

    response = Response(response_data, status=201)
    return response
```

This is a view, it runs the main script, and from the code above it just gets the response, and just gives it to the user.

```
class ExportView(APIView):
    # permission_classes = (IsAdmin,)

    def post(self, request):
        request = request.data

        if not request:
            return Response(
                {'error': 'in request incorrect data.'},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )

        return get_product_list(request)
```

As a result, it can hang like this for half an hour, and when it finally gives (it happens not always), the CPU is released, but the RAM is not released.

The query itself runs on a non-generator, so as not to carry the entire query, or it takes up about 8 gigabytes that way

```
...
    for product in product_list.iterator(chunk_size=10000): # +- 156.000 data
        yield product
```

No response comes, after performing the functionality of exporting data written to a file, everything runs, the file is saved, but the last step, give a response, takes an incredibly long time to run.

Comment: so `save_data_in_csv_file` is `get_product_list`?

Comment: almost, there's a data record going on under the hood, get what you need from the query, and get_product_list returns:

```
...
return save_data_in_csv_file(df_jewelry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ORM if you are working with millions of rows in a file.
I rewrote the code to work with raw SQL, and after that the response to the user comes normally, without strange delays and cpu eating.
Apparently, the garbage collector or ORM itself is hard to cope with such a huge amount of data.